# Dystopian story about poor people "lying" medically in order to benefit financially

Tags: story-identification

This novel, set a hundred or so years into the future, involves a doctor and a girl, as well as her family.

The doctor gives a drug to the girl to treat her. She has been falsely claimed not to be allergic to it and when she dies her impoverished family are paid for her death.

Comment: What are the science fiction aspect to this story?  So far what you have described does not have any SF element.   Was this a book, TV episode or film?  How long ago did you read / see it?

Comment: It's been a few years.  This is definitely a book or part of one.  I don't know who the author is.  As for its sci-fi credentials, I think it takes place maybe a hundred years in the future.

Comment: The checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) might help you to remember some more details.

Comment: How do you know it's dystopian? What about it made it seem futuristic? What was the girl's name? What condition was she being treated for? Why did her dying get them money? What was the Doctor's name? How did they get the money (e.g. through the courts?) Why didn't he know that she was allergic? Did he get a consent? Was this incident the main plot (e.g. spanning hundreds of pages) or just a single incident that occurred?

Comment: I don't have that many details about it.  I do know that people had to sign something saying that they or their children were not deathly allergic to it.  They deliberately lied in order to sue the doctor for her death.  The family was obviously desperate to do such a thing.  It seems to me that almost everyone in the story was destitute.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to remember a short story mostly fitting this description. It turned out to be "[The Mountain to Mohammed](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41137)" by Nancy Kress.

Differences from the OP's description: short story rather than a novel, near future rather than 100 years, and the family are background characters and probably never actually get any money (malpractice insurance won't pay and the doctor is broke).

---

Written in 1992 and set in about 2004, it envisions a United States where health insurance companies can deny coverage to people based on their gene scans. "Uninsurables" can't get insurance and so can't afford any health care. No reputable companies will hire them so they wind up in slums or homeless, doing dangerous work for cash under the table where they can get any work at all. Doctors *can* treat uninsurables at their own risk, but malpractice insurance won't cover them for such treatment and hospital employment contracts can (and typically do) forbid it.

The main character is a medical resident who has twice before treated uninsurables after being recruited by a like-minded doctor. In the story he treats a young girl for appendicitis, giving her a miracle immune-boosting drug since her genescan shows she's not allergic. Turns out the guy who brought him lied about being from his contact, the genescan was someone else's, and the girl dies from the allergic reaction. He gets sued for malpractice by the family, loses his job, girlfriend, and everything else, and gets rejected for every other residency and job he applies for. Through a few events he winds up setting up shop in the slums treating uninsurables with what equipment and drugs people can get for him. The story ends about a year later outside the court where the malpractice case is about to start. He (finally) sees the guy who had brought him to the girl out there, but doesn't get any answers, and he goes in hoping it won't take long because he has several patients waiting for him.

Comment: Just what I came here to suggest

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Marissa Meyer's [*Cinder*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1250007208)?

It is set roughly 100 years into the future. There was a doctor, and also a girl who is a cyborg. The doctor injects the girl with a medicine, and then her family would get money, but the girl lies to them (the family isn't very nice). There's a lot more plot than just this. A few problems: The family is not very impoverished, but they don't give the girl many luxuries. It was a plague, but the family probably had to sign something to verify cyborgness. I don't remember anything about allergies, or plans to sue.

Comment: Can you provide any details the fit the points the OP remembered?

Comment: It was a book and there was deliberate lying, plus the character similarities mentioned above